# Retrieve value from field attribute C#

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I created some custom attribute to apply it on a class member:

```
    [
        System.AttributeUsage(
            AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true
        )
    ]
    internal class ActionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private Action action;

        public ActionAttribute(Action action)
        {
            this.action = action;
        }

        public Action getThis()
        {
            return this.action;
        }

    }
```

But am struggling on how to retrieve it's value using reflection.

This is my attempt:

```
public static Device Serialize(string deviceName, Dictionary<string, dynamic> fields)
{
    var itce = devices[deviceName];
    Type objectType = itce.GetType();
    MemberInfo[] fieldsInfo = objectType.GetMembers();

    foreach (var field in fieldsInfo.Where(p => p.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
        object[] actionAttributes = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionAttribute), false);
        foreach (var cAttr in actionAttributes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attrs: " + cAttr.GetType());
        }
    }
    return itce;
}
```

Where in the variable `itce` I just retrieve a previously allocated instance of a type that contains those attributes using a factory pattern.

The thing I want it's *is actual value*, but I only can read it's class definition full name. It's obvious, I am asking for it to the `GetType()` method, but I have only four opts available like `ToString()` and things like that. I am imagine that I am missing some type cast probably? Don't know. Hope someone could help me with this.

BTW, `Action` type it's just an enum:

```
enum Action
{
    Read,
    Write
}
```

and, a simple example of the usage of the attributes:

```
    public class Device : Display
    {
        [Action(Action.Read)]
        [Action(Action.Write)]
        public string device_name { get; set; }

        public Device(string device_name)
        {
            this.device_name = device_name;
        }
    }
```

So, the idea, it's to retrieve the value of the attribute whenever a type has a field annotated. Above, `Device` has two annotations, `Read` and `Write`. I want to recover with reflection the actual value or values attached to that field.

device_name has two attributes, so I need to recover `Action.Read` and `Action.Write`.

Thanks.

Comment: what is `devices`?

Comment: Is the value you are referring to the value of the Action enum ( a call for getVariant) ?

Comment: devices it's a map, that are stored in a factory class, to retrieve preallocated instances. 
Devices it's just a regular type, nothing in particular.

The variant does nothing in the question. I will remove it from question from clarification.

I am just asking on how to retrieve the value stored in the field attribute.

I will use Device as example again for clarification.

Comment: Do you mean you want to cast `(ActionAttribute)cAttr` and then access it?

Comment: Code edited for clarification

Comment: How can your `getThis` method have a return type of `Category` when it's returning a field of type `Action`?

Comment: @John obv, it's a bad edit. It's already fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @freakish pointed, solution it's pretty straightfoward.

```
object[] actionAttributes = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionAttribute), false);
foreach (var cAttr in actionAttributes)   
{
    var attr = (ActionAttribute)cAttr;   
    Console.WriteLine("Attrs: " + attr.getThis());
}
```

Casting the `var cAttr` to the attribute type allows me to easily access the info that holds the field attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `var` for your loop control variable and it being `object`, specify the type as your attribute:

```cs
object[] actionAttributes = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionAttribute), false);
foreach (ActionAttribute cAttr in actionAttributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attrs: " + cAttr.getThis());
}
```

Of course, you really ought to be using a public read-only property, rather than a private field and a method, to access that value.